# How to use model class in plugin?

Tags: pimcore

I try to write plugin to pimcore and need in it use User class to change user table in database. How should I do it?
Simply:

```
$user = Objects\User::getById(2);
```

doesn't work:

```
include_once(Pimcore/Model/Object/ClassDefinition/Data/Objects/User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Zend/Loader.php on line 134
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to change the system users or do you have an object class with name "User"?

Comment: So, in true i'm really new in pimcore and try to enter in existing project, I do not know exactly..
Now I have:
`$session = Auth::authenticateSession();
        $userId = $session->getId();
        $user = AbstractUser::getById($userId);`
And it give me class without data from column that I intresed.

Comment: It seems to be the system user. Which column do you want to get? Normally you can just use `$user->getYourColumnName()`

Comment: I checked it and doesn't works - class have no this method.
I need: lastpasswordedit
This column is in DB

Comment: That field doesn't seem to exist in my setup. In which table in database do you see this field?

Comment: SELECT * FROM pimcore.users;

Comment: This field doesn't exist in my system. Which Pimcore version is that? Did you try `$user->getLastpasswordedit()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107867/discussion-between-katarzyna-and-igor-benko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this way:

```
`$db = Mysql::get();
 $select = $db->select()
       ->from('users', ['lastpasswordedit'])
       ->where('id = ?', $userId);
 $stmt = $db->query($select);
 $result = $stmt->fetch();`
```

Thanks @Igor Benko !